# Maven won't look in the correct repository for my plugin

Tags: plugins, maven

My local Maven is insisting on using the default global Maven repository to look for a plugin. Unfortunately, this isn't going to work because the plugin is, in fact, only on our corporate repository. *Every* other dependancy loads correctly, including an old version of the plugin I need. Yet, `mvn install` mysteriously insists on looking on `repo1.maven.org`.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `-U` option to force Maven to reconsider each dependency?

Comment: Didn't know to try that. Tried it. Still failed. It just won't look in the corporate repository for this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.

I found the problem. The plugin's own pom.xml file is calling itself 1.9, yet it's path name calls it 1.8. So the project is requesting 1.8 and thinks its getting 1.9. So it goes off to repo1 and (unsurprisingly) can't find it.

This should be a loggable error in Maven...

Comment: No, this didn't fix it. :-( Or I was looking at the wrong entity.

Comment: Ah. Used as colleague's settings.xml file: it turns out they have the maven "central" repository specified with a different id. Doing that fixed everything.